# Does Android's DisplayMetrics' heightpixels take into account status bar and soft navigation bar?

Tags: android, api, display

I have an app where I have to deal, under certain circumstances, with the activity's total height.

The [heightPixels](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics#heightPixels) property of `getResources().getDisplayMetrics()` (called in an Accessibility Service) returns the height of the activity, excluding both the status bar and the soft navigation if present. **This is exactly what I want.**

My question is: is this behaviour standard across all devices? Will I have to take into account the status bar and or soft navigation in `getResources().getDisplayMetrics()` on a few odd devices (which I don't want to occur).

For information, my device is a Samsung Galaxy S10.

Thanks.